# How can I test a $scope.$on event in a Jasmine test?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am unit testing a controller and I want to test an event handler. Say my controller looks like:

```
myModule.controller('MasterController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
        $scope.success = true;
    });
}]);
```

Would I broadcast that in my Jasmine test? Would I emit it? Is there an accepted standard?

Comment: How did you end up testing this, @MailmanOdd?

Comment: I just added/accepted my solution, hope it helps.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The solution I came up with is as follows:

```
describe('MasterController', function() {
    var $scope, $rootScope, controller, CreateTarget;

    beforeEach(function() {
        inject(function($injector) {
            $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();

            var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');

            CreateTarget = function() {
                $controller('MasterController', {$scope: $scope});
            }
        });
    });

    describe('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
        it('should set $scope.success to true', function() {
            controller = CreateTarget();
            $rootScope.$broadcast('$locationChangeSuccess');
            expect($scope.success).toBe(true);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm confused but, Isn't that what I answered?

Comment: It's similar but calling $scope.$digest was unnecessary. In fact in my application (different than this simplified question) it was actually causing issues. Also, I believe I solved the problem before I saw your post and never checked the question again - sorry!

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is "an accepted standard" but according to [$location source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/2508b47c1a34dfc834f8fde858574f81af4d287e/src/ng/location.js#L615) the event is broadcasted, so I would mock this behavior and test it this way:

```
'use strict';

describe('MasterController', function() {
  var MasterController,
      $rootScope,
      $scope;

  beforeEach(module('myModule'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $injector, $controller) {
    $rootScope = $rootScope;
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    MasterController = $controller('MasterController', {
      '$scope': $scope
    });
    $scope.$digest();
  }));

  describe('$locationChangeSuccess event listener', function() {
    it('should set $scope.success to true', function() {
      var newUrl = 'http://foourl.com';
      var oldUrl = 'http://barurl.com'

      $scope.$apply(function() {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('$locationChangeSuccess', newUrl, oldUrl);
      });

      expect($scope.success).toBe(true);
    });
  });
});
```