# How to Test $scope.$on in an AngularJS 1.5+ Component Using Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to test that some code gets executed using $scope.$on in an AngularJS 1.5+ component. I'm not sure how to set up the $rootScope correctly in Jasmine so I can execute the broadcast. I'm using [this stackoverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24314885/how-can-i-test-a-scope-on-event-in-a-jasmine-test) and [this blog](https://puigcerber.com/2016/02/07/how-to-test-angular-1-5-components/) as a reference. Here is my code.

```
// Component
(function (app) {
  app.component('demoComponent', {
    controller: ['$scope' function ($scope) {
      $scope.$on('someBroadcast', function (data) {
        // do something with data...
      });
    }]
  });
})(angular.module('demoApp'));


// Jasmine setup
var ctrl, $rootScope, $componentController;

beforeEach(function () {
  module('demoApp');

  inject(function ($rootScope, _$componentController_) {
    ctrl = $rootScope.$new();
    $componentController = _$componentController_('demoComponent', { $scope: ctrl }, null);
  });
});
```

My code breaks down in the inject function in the Jasmine setup. Does anyone know what I need to change to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `ctrl` is the scope that you will be using inside of your controller, you can do this:

```
ctrl.$broadcast('someBroadcast', 'test', 'values, 123);
```

And as a side note, usually you will name your scopes something like `scope` or `$scope`, or maybe event `controllerScope`. `ctrl` implies that the object is a controller, which it is not.